# Serious problem with Qooxdoo 5.0.2 RpcPhp and PHP 7.x

Tags: qooxdoo

This example code work Ok with PHP 5.x, but using PHP 7.x I get bad response.
(sorry my english!)

This code should trigger a failed event, instead trigger a aborted event.
I'm using Windows 10 x64, xampp-windows-x64-7.3.6-0-VC15 (standard installation), Qooxdoo 5.0.2. and RpcPhp 1.2.0 contrib.

On Base.php you can try any of method_prueba.

Please anyone can help me with this problem. I have huge problems with my old projects. Thanks

I had forgot, I test several servers/xampp configuration (linux/windows, etc), sometimes the problem appear, sometimes not. I can't detect the origin. I think about RpcPhp 1.2.0 + PHP 7 (and maybe Windows) combined. Or some PHP 7 particular configuration.
More crazy, sometimes I get a aborted event, and sometimes I get a failed event but with code 500 and message "Server error". All with this simple example below.

Javascript:

```
var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc("services/", "comp.Base");

rpc.addListener("completed", function(e){
    var data = e.getData();

    alert("completed");

}, this);

rpc.addListener("failed", function(e){
    var data = e.getData();

    alert("failed");
    alert(qx.lang.Json.stringify(data, null, 2));

}, this);

rpc.addListener("aborted", function(e){
    var data = e.getData();

    alert("aborted");
    alert(qx.lang.Json.stringify(data, null, 2));

}, this);

rpc.callAsyncListeners(false, "prueba");
```

Base.php:

```
class class_Base
{

  public function method_prueba($params, $error) {

    $error->SetError(0, "prueba");
    return $error;

  }


  /*
  public function method_prueba($params, $error) {

    throw new JsonRpcException("prueba", 0);

  }
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the problem was the handleQooxdooDates constant, from RpcPhp 1.2.0 contrib. Setting false the problem disappear using PHP7.
After 2 years... the solution "came" to me